# Exhaustive case with monadic guard

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, monads

I have a `case` expression with a relatively large number of patterns:

```
case x of
  ... -> ...
  ... -> ...
  ... -> ...
  ... -> ...
  ...
  _ -> ...
```

One of these cases has a guard:

```
case x of
  ... -> ...
  ... -> ...
  ... | condition -> ...
    -- If condition is false, fall through to “Rest”.

  -- Rest:
  ... -> ...
  ... -> ...
  ...
  _ -> ...
```

If the guard doesn’t match, we just fall through to the remaining cases, no problem. But now I need to test the condition monadically, so I do:

```
case x of
  ... -> ...
  ... -> ...
  ... -> do
    condition <- action
    if condition
      then ...
      else ...  -- How to fall through?

  -- Rest:
  ... -> ...
  ... -> ...
  ...
  _ -> ...
```

However, I think I’ve made a misstep. There doesn’t seem to be a way of having the `else` branch proceed to the remaining cases without duplicating those branches or factoring them into a function. And either way messes with exhaustivity checking: if I want to add a case after the guard, the compiler doesn’t know whether the matches are exhaustive.

How can I change this function, or parameterise/wrap the datatype, to get exhaustiveness checking using a monadic guard?

Comment: I think you've confused yourself. You'll only enter the guard (or the `if-then-else`) if `Bar` matches. If `Bar` matched (and you reached the conditional), then you already know that `Baz`, `Quux` et al don't match, so there's no reason to continue with the `case` block.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson: Good catch. Updated the example. I’m operating on a pair of values, and it’s still possible for later cases to match.

Comment: No it's not. Can you just provide the **actual case** you are using instead of one with made up names that doesn't actually show what you are doing?

Comment: @Bakuriu: The real code is more complex, and I don’t know that it’s really relevant, but I can update the example in a moment. In reality I have a constructor `:@`, and my `Bar` case is really a match on `Ctor "Join" :@ a :@ b`, which comes before matching on the more generic case of `a :@ b`.

Comment: @JonPurdy You don't have to post your real code, but you do need to post an *actual*, executable example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 3):

One simple option would be to grab the second half of your `case` block and put it in a separate function.

```
case (x, y) of
  (Foo ..., Foo ...) -> ...
  x@(Bar ..., Bar ...) -> do
    condition <- action
    if condition
    then ...
    else rest x
  x -> rest x

rest (Baz ..., ...) = ...
rest (Var ..., ...) = ...
...
rest _ = undefined
```

It's a bit unsatisfying to use `undefined` in the fall-through case of `rest` to catch patterns which you believe should've been matched in the first half of the original `case` block. If you manage to violate the precondition (that `(Foo, Foo)` etc didn't match) then you'd get a runtime error.

Comment: If the match in the fall-through is something relatively specific like `x :@ y` (as @JonPurdy seems to have implied in a comment), you could make `rest` a two argument function to avoid having a partial function.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a fan of the approach below, but I will share it anyway:

```
fix (\proceed b -> case (x, y, b) of
  (Foo ..., Foo ..., False) -> ...
  (Bar ..., Bar ..., False) -> do
    condition <- action
    if condition
      then ...
      else proceed True
  (Baz ..., ..., _) -> ...
  (Var ..., ..., _) -> ...
  ...
) False
```

The additional flag `b` is initially false, so all the branches are considered. Once we `proceed`, we set it to true so that the first branches are skipped.

May or may not be statically found exhaustive, depending on the actual patterns.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was using a monad stack equipped with `Maybe` and replacing the `case` with `asum` over a list of actions, following this structure:

```
asum

  [ do
    pattern1 <- pure input  -- failed pattern matches fall through
    body1

  , do
    pattern2 <- pure input
    body2

  , do
    pattern1 <- pure input
    guard condition         -- guards also fall through
    body3

  , ...

  ]
```

As I recently described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49518519/246886) to someone else’s question. Unfortunately, this doesn’t allow exhaustiveness checking.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious question is : can you not untangle the pure and impure bit ?
Without the actual code is hard to tell but if only one condition is actually the problem you can do a two level cases using Either or Maybe, which capture all the specific conditions.

```
step <-case x of 
   pattern2 -> condition <- action
                if condition 
                then Just whatToDo
                else Nothing

   pattern5 -> condition <- action2
                if condition
                then Just whatToDo2

   _ -> Nothing

case step of
  Just action -> action
  Nothing -> case x of
       pattern 1 -> body1
       ....
```

Depending on your real case, you might want to use a different intermediate type, maybe even create your own custom one, or realize you actually don't even need any.