# Pattern matching in `Alternative`

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, monads

I have a function that pattern matches on its arguments to produce a computation in `StateT () Maybe ()`. This computation can fail when run, in which case I want the current pattern match branch to fail, so to speak.

I highly doubt it's possible to have something like

```
compute :: Int -> StateT () Maybe Int
compute = return

f :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> StateT () Maybe ()
f (Just n1) (Just n2) = do
  m <- compute (n1 + n2) 
  guard (m == 42)
f (Just n) _ = do
  m <- compute n
  guard (m == 42)
f _ (Just n) = do
  m <- compute n
  guard (m == 42)
```

behave in the way I want it to: When the first computation fails due to the `guard` or somewhere in `compute`, I want `f` to try the next pattern.

Obviously the above can't work, because `StateT` (as any other monad might) involves an additional parameter when expanded, so I probably can't formulate this as simple pattern guards.

The following does what I want, but it's ugly:

```
f' :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> StateT () Maybe ()
f' a b = asum (map (\f -> f a b) [f1, f2, f3])
  where
    f1 a b = do
      Just n1 <- pure a
      Just n2 <- pure b
      m <- compute (n1 + n2) 
      guard (m == 42)
    f2 a _ = do
      Just n <- pure a
      m <- compute n
      guard (m == 42)
    f3 _ b = do
      Just n <- pure b
      m <- compute n
      guard (m == 42)
```

A call like `execStateT (f (Just 42) (Just 1)) ()` would fail for `f` but return `Just ()` for `f'`, because it matches `f2`.

How do I get the behavior of `f'` while having elegant pattern matching with as little auxiliary definitions as possible like in `f`? Are there other, more elegant ways to formulate this?

---

Complete runnable example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver=lts-11.1 script

import Control.Monad.Trans.State
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Data.Foldable

compute :: Int -> StateT () Maybe Int
compute = return

f :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> StateT () Maybe ()
f (Just n1) (Just n2) = do
  m <- compute (n1 + n2) 
  guard (m == 42)
f (Just n) _ = do
  m <- compute n
  guard (m == 42)
f _ (Just n) = do
  m <- compute n
  guard (m == 42)

f' :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> StateT () Maybe ()
f' a b = asum (map (\f -> f a b) [f1, f2, f3])
  where
    f1 a b = do
      Just n1 <- pure a
      Just n2 <- pure b
      m <- compute (n1 + n2) 
      guard (m == 42)
    f2 a _ = do
      Just n <- pure a
      m <- compute n
      guard (m == 42)
    f3 _ b = do
      Just n <- pure b
      m <- compute n
      guard (m == 42)

main = do
  print $ execStateT (f (Just 42) (Just 1)) ()  -- Nothing
  print $ execStateT (f' (Just 42) (Just 1)) () -- Just (), because `f2` succeeded
```

---

**Edit**: I elicited quite some clever answers with this question so far, thanks! Unfortunately, they mostly suffer from overfitting to the particular code example I've given. In reality, I need something like this for unifying two expressions (let-bindings, to be precise), where I want to try unifying the RHS of two simultaneous lets if possible and fall through to the cases where I handle let bindings one side at a time by floating them. So, actually there's no clever structure on `Maybe` arguments to exploit and I'm not `compute`ing on `Int` actually.

The answers so far might benefit others beyond the enlightenment they brought me though, so thanks!

---

**Edit 2**: Here's some compiling example code with probably bogus semantics:

```
module Unify (unify) where

import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict

data Expr
  = Var String -- meta, free an bound vars
  | Let String Expr Expr
  -- ... more cases
  -- no Eq instance, fwiw

-- | If the two terms unify, return the most general unifier, e.g.
-- a substitution (`Map`) of meta variables for terms as association
-- list.
unify :: [String] -> Expr -> Expr -> Maybe [(String, Expr)]
unify metaVars l r = execStateT (go [] [] l r) [] -- threads the current substitution as state
  where
    go locals floats (Var x) (Var y)
      | x == y = return ()
    go locals floats (Var x) (Var y)
      | lookup x locals == Just y = return ()
    go locals floats (Var x) e
      | x `elem` metaVars = tryAddSubstitution locals floats x e
    go locals floats e (Var y)
      | y `elem` metaVars = tryAddSubstitution locals floats y e
    -- case in point:
    go locals floats (Let x lrhs lbody) (Let y rrhs rbody) = do
      go locals floats lrhs rrhs -- try this one, fail current pattern branch if rhss don't unify
      -- if we get past the last statement, commit to this branch, no matter
      -- the next statement fails or not
      go ((x,y):locals) floats lbody rbody
    -- try to float the let binding. terms mentioning a floated var might still
    -- unify with a meta var
    go locals floats (Let x rhs body) e = do
      go locals (Left (x,rhs):floats) body e
    go locals floats e (Let y rhs body) = do
      go locals (Right (y,rhs):floats) body e

    go _ _ _ _ = empty

    tryAddSubstitution = undefined -- magic
```

Comment: Perhaps this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526768/is-there-in-haskell-something-similar-to-sub-guards

Comment: "computation can fail when run, in which case I want the whole pattern match to fail, so to speak" seem to contradict with "When the first computation fails due to the guard or somewhere in compute, I want f to try the next pattern". If you want to have 2 types of failures - permanent and try next pattern, then you should have 2 layers of Maybe

Comment: I think it's pretty clear from the code he means that the computation under the current branch should fail.

Comment: Exactly. I edited that part.

Comment: What is your case spliting pattern for a b? Maybe it can be done another way. Something like generateCases a b >>= asum commute

Comment: Edit: generateCases a b >>= asum (commute >>= guard (==42))

Comment: Regarding your edit, could you perhaps give such a more complex example?

Comment: I added a more concrete unification example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I need something like this, I just use `asum` with the blocks inlined. Here I also condensed the multiple patterns `Just n1 <- pure a; Just n2 <- pure b` into one, `(Just n1, Just n2) <- pure (a, b)`.

```
f :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> StateT () Maybe ()
f a b = asum

  [ do
    (Just n1, Just n2) <- pure (a, b)
    m <- compute (n1 + n2) 
    guard (m == 42)

  , do
    Just n <- pure a
    m <- compute n
    guard (m == 42)

  , do
    Just n <- pure b
    m <- compute n
    guard (m == 42)

  ]
```

You can also use chains of `<|>`, if you prefer:

```
f :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> StateT () Maybe ()
f a b

  = do
    (Just n1, Just n2) <- pure (a, b)
    m <- compute (n1 + n2) 
    guard (m == 42)

  <|> do
    Just n <- pure a
    m <- compute n
    guard (m == 42)

  <|> do
    Just n <- pure b
    m <- compute n
    guard (m == 42)
```

This is about as minimal as you can get for this kind of “fallthrough”.

Comment: I think I'll go with something like this in the end. But I'll wait for some more input before I decide which answer to accept.

Answer (score 3):

If you were using `Maybe` alone, you would be able to do this with pattern guards:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative

ensure :: Alternative f => (a -> Bool) -> a -> f a
ensure p a = a <$ guard (p a)

compute :: Int -> Maybe Int
compute = return

f :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
f (Just m) (Just n)
    | Just x <- ensure (== 42) =<< compute (m + n)
    = return x
f (Just m) _
    | Just x <- ensure (== 42) =<< compute m
    = return x
f _ (Just n)
    | Just x <- ensure (== 42) =<< compute n
    = return x
f _ _ = empty
```

(`ensure` is a general purpose combinator. Cf. [*Lift to Maybe using a predicate*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49281530/2751851))

As you have `StateT` on the top, though, you would have to supply a state in order to pattern match on `Maybe`, which would foul up everything. That being so, you are probably better off with something in the vein of your "ugly" solution. Here is a whimsical attempt at improving its looks:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Data.Foldable

ensure :: Alternative f => (a -> Bool) -> a -> f a
ensure p a = a <$ guard (p a)

compute :: Int -> StateT () Maybe Int
compute = return

f :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> StateT () Maybe Int
f a b = asum (map (\c -> f' (c a b)) [liftA2 (+), const, flip const])
    where
    f' = ensure (== 42) <=< compute <=< lift
```

> While this is an answer specific to the snippet I've given, the refactorings only apply limited to the code I was facing.

Perhaps it's not that far-fetched of an idea to extract the skeleton of the `asum` expression above to a more general combinator:

```
-- A better name would be welcome.
selector :: Alternative f => (a -> a -> a) -> (a -> f b) -> a -> a -> f b
selector g k x y = asum (fmap (\sel -> k (sel x y)) [g, const, flip const])

f :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> StateT () Maybe Int
f = selector (liftA2 (+)) (ensure (== 42) <=< compute <=< lift)
```

Though it is perhaps a bit awkward of a combinator, `selector` does show the approach is more general than it might appear at first: the only significant restriction is that `k` has to produce results in some `Alternative` context.

P.S.: While writing `selector` with `(<|>)` instead of `asum` is arguably more tasteful...

```
selector g k x y = k (g x y) <|> k x <|> k y
```

... the `asum` version straightforwardly generalises to an arbitrary number of pseudo-patterns:

```
selector :: Alternative f => [a -> a -> a] -> (a -> f b) -> a -> a -> f b
selector gs k x y = asum (fmap (\g -> k (g x y)) gs)
```

Comment: See my last edit. While this is an answer specific to the snippet I've given, the refactorings only apply limited to the code I was facing. This was helpful nonetheless!

Comment: @SebastianGraf Though I might be missing something, I think this strategy is more general than it might appear at first sight. See my latest edit.

Comment: I don't think I can factor my `compute`ation into an `a -> a -> a` and a `a -> f b`, because the branches have quite different logic actually, which probably leaves me with something like the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could get rid of the whole pattern match by relying on the fact that `Int` forms a `Monoid` with addition and `0` as the identity element, and that `Maybe a` forms a `Monoid` if `a` does. Then your function becomes:

```
f :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> StateT () Maybe Int
f a b = pure $ a <> b >>= compute >>= pure . mfilter (== 42)
```

You could generalise by passing the predicate as an argument:

```
f :: Monoid a => (a -> Bool) -> Maybe a -> Maybe a -> StateT () Maybe a
f p a b = pure $ a <> b >>= compute >>= pure . mfilter p
```

The only thing is that `compute` is now taking a `Maybe Int` as input, but that is just a matter of calling `traverse` inside that function with whatever computation you need to do.

---

**Edit**: Taking into account your last edit, I find that if you spread your pattern matches into separate computations that may fail, then you can just write

```
f a b = f1 a b <|> f2 a b <|> f3 a b
  where f1 (Just a) (Just b) = compute (a + b) >>= check
        f1 _        _        = empty
        f2 (Just a) _        = compute a >>= check
        f2 _        _        = empty
        f3 _        (Just b) = compute b >>= check
        f3 _        _        = empty
        check x              = guard (x == 42)
```

Comment: See my latest edit at the bottom of the question. I'm afraid this solution is too overfitted to the code snippet I've given.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the update. In effect, you're saying there is no `Maybe Int` but instead some `f a` representing RHS expressions, am I right? Another observation is that your computation does not care  which branch of the pattern match is taken: does that still hold?

Comment: The computation is actually different for each branch. But something like what you suggested is what I would end up writing in absence of a better idea.